# Is it possible to combine buffer zone analysis with time series analysis in QGIS?

Tags: buffer, area, time, analysis

There is a multitemporal analyzer in QGIS where it is possible to do a buffer zone analysis combined with time series analysis, where there are two layers an input layer and a target layer and the effect of objects on the input layer can be analyzed the environment of the objects on the target layer specified distances? For example, we have a layer of a city road network with the data of car traffic in the roads, and there is a layer of roadside homes in the city with the data of cancer patients in homes, and can be analyzed that to air pollution on the road, on the input layer within what distances and to what extent it causes cancer on the target layer. How does the number of cancers change depending on the distance from the car's road? If we have carried out buffer zone analysis for several years, say in 2002, 2003, 2004 and 2005 then in the multitemporal analyzer these layers and the analyzed data of the years could be grouped, and time series analysis could be done about it that how the impact of road-side air pollution on cancers has changed at specified distances from year to year. Data should not only be analyzed across the whole layers but also within an Optionally selected part of the layers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, GIS SE uses a "Focused question / Best answer" model, while you have a laundry list of capabilities. The general trend in GIS software is to provides a number of capabilities, and let the users assemble them as needed via a scripting language like Python. What you are requesting is more like an engineered solution, and therefore far too broad.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a single, focused question.

Comment: I shortened the question. If you consider it necessary, I'm still editing it.